# Indy 10 UdpClient and Open Sound Control

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, osc, delphi-10.3-rio

To control a **Behringer X32 audio mixer**, I have to send an OSC message like `/ch/01/mix/fader ,f .3` to move a fader to `30%`. The mixer, per the OSC protocol, is expecting the `.3` to come in as a 4 character string - in hex it's `3E 99 99 9A`. So special characters are involved.

`TIdUDPClient` is given the characters for `3E 99 99 9A`, but it sends out `3E 3F 3F 3F`. Likewise `.4` wants to be `3E CC CC CD` but `3E 3F 3F 3F` is sent.

When you get up to `.5` and greater, things work again as the characters are below `3F`. For example, `.6` should be `3F 19 99 9A` and goes out as `3F 19 3F 3F`.

Evidently the Behringer is only looking at the first two characters there.

I am using **Delphi Rio** with the **Indy 10** version distributed with it. I can create a module in **Lazarus** with **Lnet** that works fine. But my main application is in Delphi where I need this ability. As you can see, I've tried several different ways with the same non-working result.

How do I send the proper characters?

```
procedure TCPForm1.OSCSendMsg;
var
  OutValueStr: String;
  I: Integer;
  J: Tbytes;
  B1: TIdbytes;
begin
  If Length(CommandStr) > 0 then begin
    OscCommandStr := PadStr(CommandStr);        //convert CommandStr to OSC string
    If TypeStr='' then OscCommandStr := OscCommandStr+','+#0+#0+#0;
    If Length(TypeStr) = 1 then begin
      If TypeStr='i' then Begin     // Parameter is an integer
              I := swapendian(IValue);              //change to big endian
              OscCommandStr := OscCommandStr+','+TypeStr+#0+#0+IntToCharStr(I);
              OutValueStr   := IntToStr(IValue);
            end;
      If TypeStr='f' then Begin     // Parameter is a float (real)
              I := swapendian(PInteger(@FValue)^);   //typecast & change to big endian
              //I := htonl(PInteger(@FValue)^);   //typecast & change to big endian
              //J := MakeOSCFloat(FValue);
              OscCommandStr := OscCommandStr+','+TypeStr+#0+#0+IntToCharStr(I);
              //OscCommandStr := OscCommandStr+','+TypeStr+#0+#0+char(J[0])+char(J[1])+char(J[2])+char(J[3]);
              OutValueStr   := FloatToStr(FValue);
            end;
    end;
  //IdUDPClient2.Send(OSCCommandStr,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  //IdUDPClient2.Send(OSCCommandStr);
  B1 := toBytes(OSCCommandStr);
  IdUDPClient2.SendBuffer(B1);
   if loglevel>0 then logwrite('OSC= '+ hexstr(OSCCommandStr));
   Wait(UDPtime);
//   if loglevel>0 then logwrite('OSC '+ OSCCommandStr);
  end;
end;

function  TCPForm1.IntToCharStr(I : Integer) : String;
var
  CharStr : String;
  MyArray: array [0..3] of Byte;
  J: Integer;
begin
  For J :=0 to 3 do MyArray[J] := 0;
  Move(I, MyArray, 4);  //typeset conversion from integer to array of byte
  CharStr := '';
  For J :=0 to 3 do     //convert array of byte to string
    CharStr := CharStr+char(MyArray[J]);
  IntToCharStr := CharStr;
end;
```

**UPDATE**:

The system would not let me add this as an answer, so...

Thank you, Remy. At least as far as the X32 software simulator is concerned, adding the 8 bit text encoding gives the correct response. I'll have to wait until tomorrow to test on the actual mixer in the theater. A byte array might be better if we had control of both ends of the communication. As it is, I can't change the X32 and it wants to get a padded string (in Hex: 2F 63 68 2F 30 31 2F 6D 69 78 2F 66 61 64 65 72 00 00 00 00 2C 66 00 00 3E CC CC CD)  for the text string "/ch/01/mix/fader ,f .4". The documentation of messages the X32 responds to is a long table of similar messages with different parameters. e.g. "/ch/01/mix/mute on", "/bus/1/dyn/ratio ,i 2", etc. This is all in accordance with the Open Sound Control protocol.

As always, you are the definitive source of Indy wisdom, so, thank you. I'll edit this note after my results with the actual device.

**UPDATE**:

Confirmed that the addition of 8 bit text encoding to the Send command works with the X32. Cheers! A couple questions as a result of this:

1. Is one send construct preferred over the other?
2. Where should I have read/learned more about these details of Indy?

Comment: Can’t this message be send using ansi characters (ansistring) or does it require a specific binary format?

Comment: The OSC protocol is specific as to characters, padding, and endian use. Take a peek at my answer.

Comment: Re your deleted answer: it's  not a question of offending anyone, just that Answers are for answers, not for comments.  If you consider that @Remy's answer has answered the point you were asking, all you need do is to click the tick icon on its LHS.  This is useful to readers because it tells them that the answer is worth looking at (Remy's invariably are), i.e. it helps increase the signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: @Dgbaxter UDP operates on bytes only, not on strings. Strings are transmitted as bytes. You don't need to change anything on the X32 to use byte arrays in your own code (case in point, your `ToBytes()` example). I think you need to read up on the correlation between 8bit strings and 8bit bytes. They are the same data. You can use byte arrays to build up your OSC messages, especially for the portions that don't involve human-readable characters. Just something to consider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3F` is the ASCII `'?'` character. You are seeing that character being sent when a Unicode character is encoded to a byte encoding that doesn't support that Unicode character. For example, Indy's default text encoding is **US-ASCII** unless you specify otherwise (via the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal.pas` unit, or via various class properties or method parameters), and US-ASCII does not support Unicode characters > U+007F.

It seems like you are dealing with a binary protocol, not a text protocol, so why are you using strings to create its messages? I would think byte arrays would make more sense.

At the very least, try using Indy's 8-bit text encoding (via the `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit()` function in the `IdGlobal.pas` unit) to convert Unicode characters U+0000..U+00FF to bytes 0x00..0xFF without data loss, eg:

```pascal
B1 := ToBytes(OSCCommandStr, IndyTextEncoding_8Bit); // not ASCII or UTF8!
IdUDPClient2.SendBuffer(B1);
```

```pascal
IdUDPClient2.Send(OSCCommandStr, IndyTextEncoding_8Bit); // not ASCII or UTF8!
```